# My bubble sort algorithm does not sort the array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BubbleSort{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter value: ");
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if(array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Sorted Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

When I input an array. The output is:

```
Enter value: 
5
Enter value: 
4
Enter value: 
3
Enter value: 
2
Enter value: 
1
Sorted Array: 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: check your swap logic.  where are you setting `temp`?

Comment: change `array[j + 1] = array[j];` to `array[j + 1] = temp;`

Comment: Nice title to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integer swapping logic is incorrect.

replace this line

```
array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

with

```
array[j + 1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

`array[j + 1] = array[j];`

to this

`array[j + 1] = temp;`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BubbleSort{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter value: ");
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if(array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp; // ###### here is the change ######
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Sorted Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Improvement

In every step, the largest element is moving in right-most position. So you don't need the inner loop to iterate to far right every time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) { // early pruning of loop
        if(array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You and the OP hast implemented Selection Sort rather than Bubble Sort.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt Take a look https://github.com/kaidul/Data_Structure_and_Algorithms_Library/blob/master/algorithms/Selection_Sort.cpp

Comment: So Sorry.. Apologies..!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to assign the temp back:

```
array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

should be

```
array[j + 1] = temp;
```

Besides, since the right side of the array are already sorted, you could skip the that part in the inner loop execution to gain a performance boost.

This is my complete code if you'd like to see the full reference.

```
public int[] bubbleSort(int[] list) {
  int len = list.length;
  if (len <= 1) 
    return list;

  for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
     // The right side of the list is ordered and have no need to check
    for (int j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) { 
      if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
        int temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }     
}
```